# Alarm Local Notification at IOS 7 Locked screen Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, localnotification

I'm practicing to develop Alarm app like Alarm on IOS 7.
[Alarm time up on IOS7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6yYF.jpg)
However, I stuck at local notification at locked screen, it just like this.
[My notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8w9T.png)
Some code I did:

In my AppDelegate.m

**My code**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    // Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

....
..in my ViewController.m..

[self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:correctDate];
....
(void)scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate {

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alert Fired at %@", fireDate];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = numberReminder;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Who can help to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Third-party apps don’t get to appear on the lock screen the way the system alarm-clock app does—your app can only produce ordinary notifications. If you’d like an API added to get the full-screen alert style, you might try [filing an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Can you explain more about API?

Answer (score -1):

```
 if([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}

UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if(notification) {       
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

And in View Controller.m call this function

```
- (void) Notify {
NSDate *fireDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
fireDate = self.datePicker.date;    

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComp = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute| NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:fireDate];    

NSDate *dd = [cal dateByAddingComponents:dateComp toDate:fireDate options:0];    

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setFireDate:dd]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

}

Comment: This… just tries to do what the OP’s code already does, only it doesn’t even work since you’re not calling `+scheduleLocalNotification:` with the notification after creating it.

Comment: Sorry about the incomplete code, Have edited now. Hope this works.